# looping elements without a wrapper element in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I have the following code which I would like to generate through a `v-for`:

```
<div class="rating-container">
    <input type="radio" name="star" value="5" id="star-5">
    <label class="star-radio" for="star-5">5</label>
    <input type="radio" name="star" value="4" id="star-4">
    <label class="star-radio" for="star-4">4</label>
    <input type="radio" name="star" value="3" id="star-3">
    <label class="star-radio" for="star-3">3</label>
    <input type="radio" name="star" value="2" id="star-2">
    <label class="star-radio" for="star-2">2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="star" value="1" id="star-1">
    <label class="star-radio" for="star-1">1</label>
</div>
```

But I need to keep them in the same order, I mean, a `label` right after the radio `input` element, I know `v-for` on the `input` tag or the `label` element would generate all the `input`s first and then all the `label`s

Is there any way to do this with vuejs `v-for` so that I can preserve the element order and generate them with a loop ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the template tag as

> The template element holds HTML code without displaying it

```
<div id="app">
<div class="rating-container" >
  <template v-for="n in 5">
    <input type="radio" name="star" :value="n" :id="'star-'+ n">
    <label class="star-radio" :for="'star-'+ n">{{n}}</label>
  </template>
</template>
</div>
```

If you want to loop trough the items in a reversed way you have to do it yourself